# How to use a FluentQuery from a Func?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm having difficluty with a func property.

I have the following code with a property for `Button`, which is assigned in the constructor of 'MyClass`. However, I'd like to reuse` Button`in`MyMethod` without having to re-specify the query.

```
using Query = System.Func<Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery, 
                          Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery>;
    
public class MyClass {
    readonly Query Button;
    
    public MyClass() {
        Button = x => x.Id("MyButton");
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        var result = app.Query(x => x.Id("MyButton")).FirstOrDefault();
    
        // Would like something shorter instead of something
        var result = something.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that using `AppResult[] results = app.Query (Button );` to replace `app.Query(x => x.Id("MyButton"))`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I’m looking to reuse what I have assigned in the constructor. So I can just call FirstDefault on it.

Comment: just one button that id="MyButton" in constructor, if you want to query this button, I think you need to call app.Query function.